# Function name generation and calling in C++

Tags: c++, function, macros

I have 10 functions with generic names which return references like:

```
int& function0();
int& function1();
...int& functionN();
```

As you can see only one letter changes in the function name. Each function does a different job. My use case is given some length, say L, I have to call functions from 0 to L. So I want to somehow generate these function names and call them instead of hardcoding all the function calls based on L. So if in a loop where index i is from 0 to L, for each i I want to call functioni().

One approach that I tried was to store these functions into an array of function pointers but that does not work as these functions return references and array of references is not possible. I also tried to use macro concatenation to generate function names but that is also not possible because macro cannot substitute the value of some variable at preprocessing (MACRO(function,i) does not substitute value of i, concatenates to functioni).

How can I do such thing in C++?

Comment: Why not make all those functions into a single function, pass `i` as an argument, and use `if` statements to check the value of `i`, and depending on it, return the right reference.

Comment: I cannot alter the code of the functions.

Comment: Then create a new function which calls these functions depending on the value of `i`.

Comment: Then you will have to hard code in that function, you will have to check what i was passed to the function and then call that function. Please don't give a work around solution. I want to know if such a thing is possible in C++ and if yes how?

Comment: Does the order matter? If you can call them from L to 0, you can write a wicked switch statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible in C++, but in your case an array of function pointers seems like a good solution:

```
typedef int& (* functionPtr)();
functionPtr functions[N];
// or without typedef: int& (* functions[N])();
functions[0] = foo; // assign a function named foo to index 0
int& i = functions[0](); // call function at index 0
```

Comment: Thanks zenith! This seems to solve the problem. I also tried to use array of function pointers but did not use typedef. I directly created an array of function pointers for functions which were returning references. This failed as array of references is not possible.

PS. You probably want to say functions[0] in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You could store an array of function pointers, as [answered by Zenith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690130/841108).

In [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you could have an array of function [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), e.g. use [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). You could have some `std::map<std:string,std::function<int&(void)>>` associating names to closures.

You could wrap the calls in some function like

```
int& dofunction(int n) {
 switch 0: return function0();
 switch 1: return function1();
 /// etc...
};
```

and you could write some small script (e.g. in awk, python, shell, etc....) to generate the C++ code of the above `dofunction`.

At last, on some operating systems (e.g. Linux and most POSIX), you could retrieve a function pointer at runtime by its name using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (with a `NULL` filename) then `dlsym`. You would then declare `extern "C" int& function0();` (to avoid [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) -otherwise you need to pass the mangled name to `dlsym`) and you need to link the program with `-rdynamic -ldl`; see [C++ dlopen mini howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/).